# JUnit4: is() vs is(notNullValue())

Tags: java, junit4, assertions

Regarding JUnit4 `assertThat`, I have seen this done both ways. Is one correct over the other or is it all the same?

```
byte[] val;
...
assertThat(val, notNullValue());
        --vs--
assertThat(val, is(notNullValue()));
```

The second option reads "assert that val is not null" which sounds better. (On the other hand, it may be redundant.)

I have used both ways and they seem to produce correct results.

Comment: If the purpose is to assert that a value is not null, I would simply use `Assert.assertNotNull(val)`.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl: I'm using assertThat instead of assertNotNull because the message printed gives more information (e.g. something along the lines of: "expected X, but X was null").

Comment: I understand. How about `assertNull(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object object)` then? :) Which accepts a message.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl: Thanks for the hint but I'd still have to write the message. With `assertThat` I get the nice output without extra work. The less I have to code the better!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Hamcrest documentation](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) says:

> Hamcrest strives to make your tests as readable as possible. For example, **the `is` matcher is a wrapper that doesn't add any extra behavior to the underlying matcher. The following assertions are all equivalent**:
>
> ```
> assertThat(theBiscuit, equalTo(myBiscuit));
> assertThat(theBiscuit, is(equalTo(myBiscuit)));
> assertThat(theBiscuit, is(myBiscuit));
> ```
>
> The last form is allowed since `is(T value)` is overloaded to return `is(equalTo(value))`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the link. I read the JUnit wiki but not the Hamcret documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between this two ways. The `is()` method was mainly introduced to improve readability.